# Data binding- get resource by dynamic id - Android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have `ErrorEmptyPage.java` :

```
public class ErrorEmptyPage {

    private int iconId;
    private int messageId;
    private int actionTextId;

    public int getIconId() {
        return iconId;
    }

    public void setIconId(int iconId) {
        this.iconId = iconId;
    }

    public int getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(int messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public int getActionTextId() {
        return actionTextId;
    }

    public void setActionTextId(int actionTextId) {
        this.actionTextId = actionTextId;
    }

}
```

Then I fill it in my `activity` :

```
        ErrorEmptyPage errorEmptyPage = new ErrorEmptyPage();
        errorEmptyPage.setIconId(iconId);
        errorEmptyPage.setMessageId(messageId);<=== for example R.string.fetching_data_failed
        errorEmptyPage.setActionTextId(actionTextId);
activityStartBinding.contentInstagramEmpty.setMessageEmptyView(errorEmptyPage);
```

And in my `xml` I have a `include` item that contain bellow `xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="messageEmptyView"
            type="ir.jmostafa.appportalmostafa.start.models.ErrorEmptyPage" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view_icon_icontextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{@string/messageEmptyView.iconId}"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view_message_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@{@string/messageEmptyView.messageId}" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/empty_view_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{@string/messageEmptyView.actionTextId}"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Then I fill items of include `xml` like bellow:

```
android:text="@{@string/messageEmptyView.messageId}"
```

But get me bellow error :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
<com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconTextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view_icon_icontextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(messageEmptyView.iconId)}"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

and you have to import below line in .. like below.

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="messageEmptyView"
            type="ir.jmostafa.appportalmostafa.start.models.ErrorEmptyPage" />

<import type="java.lang.string" />
    </data>
```

**Update Answer.**

And if you want to user value from String.xml then, you have to write like below,

```
android:text="@{@string/invitation_invited_by_user(invitation.occasion.user.firstName, invitation.occasion.user.lastName)}"
```

and value from String.xml like

```
<string name="invitation_invited_by_user" formatted="false">%s %s</string>
```

Comment: you have do same thing for your `iconId` because its also `int`, check my updated answer.

Comment: I can't get any value from string xml .I just see digit .

Comment: what you exactly want? you want to display text from your response or you want to show text from string.xml?

Comment: check my updated answer, if you want to use text from String.xml file.

Answer (score -1):

```
 android:text=@{String.valueOf (messageEmptyView.messageId)}
```

Your messageId is `int` and you cannot put `int` in `android:text`